# Reference for a proof of the fiberwise Stokes theorem

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, integration, differential-forms

The fiberwise Stokes theorem says that given a differential form on a smooth fiber bundle whose fibers have boundary,
the difference between the fiberwise integral of the differential and the differential of its fiberwise integral is, up to a sign,
the fiberwise integral of the restriction of the form to the boundary.

Is there a citeable reference for a proof of this result? For the sake of being definite, let's say that “citeable” means indexed by Mathematical Reviews or Zentralblatt, or available on arXiv.

Of course, for such a well-known result I would very much prefer an older, classical reference as opposed to something recent on arXiv.

Citeable reference for a statement of this theorem without proof do exist, the earliest one that I am aware of is Greub-Halperin-van Stone I, Chapter VII, Problem 4. References which do not include proofs will not suffice for my purposes.

Comment: Try Propositions 3.4.54 of [these notes](http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Lectures.pdf). (It is indexed by Math Rev. and Zentralblatt.)

Comment: Yes, but this is the version without boundary.  (In fact, I'm not sure if the name “Stokes theorem” can be applied to the case of an empty boundary.)

Comment: Sorry. I misqouted the theorem. It is Theorem  3.4.54 of the same notes. Unfortunately, I a also left the proof as an exercise.

Comment: Yes, my point exactly.  I know several other references that leave it as an exercise, but for some strange reason none of them prove it, even though it's not difficult.